# How to find a specific component in Altium PCB

Tags: pcb, altium, software

When viewing a PCB (`.pcbdoc`) layout in Altium, is there a way to search for a specific component by name?  Like "highlight C35 and show it on the screen"?

Comment: (Not the same as https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/256883/142, which is about PDF files)

Comment: Alternatively, if you are working in a project and have the schematic open, you can click on the component in the schematic and it should be highlighted on the PCB.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Key in 'j', 'c', and enter the designator. "(J)ump"->"(C)omponent".

This works in the schematic editor as well.

Alternatively, open the PCB panel, and select 'Components' in the top drop-down selection.  Sort the available columns by designator, and click on the component of choice.

The zoom level and highlight mode, for the targeted component, are both configurable in preferences.

Comment: Where in the world is this documented!? How can I learn these things on my own?

Comment: Search the official Altium forum for 'hotkeys' or 'shortcuts'.  Also: https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/shortcut-keys.  However, the J-C combo is likely a menu-defined 'Accelerator' key sequence (described on the same page).  There are too many to remember them all, so one typically 'keys-in' on a few select favorites.  ;~)